# tensorflow declare and update multiple model

Tags: python, tensorflow, model, declare

I'm beginner of python and tensor. I have some problems with tensorflow

I want to something like

```
def discriminator(..):
  ...
  return logits

def generator(..):
  ...
  return imgs

nb_teachers = 100
disc_teachers = discriminator[nb_teachers]
disc_student = disriminator
generator = generator 
opt = None
for disc in disc_teachers:
  x = imgs(batch_size)
  z = rand(batch_size)
  fake = generator(z)
  d_logit, f_logit = disc(x), disc(fake)
loss = -tf.reduce_mean(tf.log(d_logit) + tf.log(1-f_logit))
opt[i] = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.03).minimize(loss, var_list=disc's var)
  ...
```

I don't know how to declare and update multiple discriminator like above with same 'discriminator graph'

In this code, generator and disc_student update with disc_teachers' vote([0,1])

Please let me know how I can declare and update multiple same graph mode

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your question correctly, You want to make several models that have same graph, and totally separated (don't have any sharing variables).

Each variables of each models can be distinguished by their own variable name. and you can divide and define variable name hierarchical using `with variable_scope(any_scope_name) as scope:`  (reference : [variable_scope](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/variable_scope))

and you can update each separated variables like this,,

```
var_list1 = [ i for i in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES,scope='some_scope1')]
var_list2 = [ i for i in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES,scope='some_scope2')]
opt1 = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.03).minimize(loss1, var_list=var_list1)
opt2 = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.03).minimize(loss2, var_list=var_list2)
```